# Objective-c: NSString to enum

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, enums

So, I've got this definition:

```
typedef enum {
    red = 1,
    blue = 2,
    white = 3
} car_colors;
```

Then, I've got a variable of type car_colors:
car_colors myCar;

The question is, I receive the color of the car in a NSString. It must be a NSString, I can't change that. How can I convert from NSString to car_colors type?

```
NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"1"];
myCar = [value intValue]; // <-- doesn't work
```

any idea?
thanks!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Put a breakpoint in the method where you're converting the string to an integer, you should be able to see exactly what part is going haywire.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rather than use an array, why not use a dictionary; You have the colour NSString as keys, and you return whatever NSNumber you want. Something like; (Long winded for clarity).

```
NSDictionary *carColourDictionary = @{@"Red": @1,
                                      @"Blue": @2,
                                      @"White": @3};

// Use the dictionary to get the number
// Assume you have a method that returns the car colour as a string:
// - (NSString *)colourAsString;
int carColour = carColourDictionary[object colourAsString];
```

Comment: Enum has a different meaning, we cant replace the enum with NSArray or NSDictionary. When you develop libraries you must use proper datatypes. This is not a optimal solution for it.

Comment: @AntoBinishKaspar The question wasn't about a library it was about working around a particular problem with a particular constraint. And who says you can't replace an enum with a dictionary? I'm not talking about a drop in replacement, I'm talking about a different way of approaching a solution.

Answer (score 53):

here's an implementation using `NSDictionary` and the existing enum

in .h file:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, City) {
    Toronto         = 0,
    Vancouver       = 1
 };

@interface NSString (EnumParser)
- (City)cityEnumFromString;
@end
```

in .m file:

```
@implementation NSString (EnumParser)

- (City)cityEnumFromString{
    NSDictionary<NSString*,NSNumber*> *cities = @{
                            @"Toronto": @(Toronto),
                            @"Vancouver": @(Vancouver),
                            };
    return cities[self].integerValue;
}

@end
```

sample usage:

```
NSString *myCity = @"Vancouver";
City enumValue = [myCity cityEnumFromString];

NSLog(@"Expect 1, Actual %@", @(enumValue));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Making your enums Arrays or Dictionaries is not a good way to approach this issue.

Comment: Note that if it the precise values of the enum aren't important, then you don't need to specify the values.

Answer (score 8):

You could also put the values in an array.

```
NSArray *carColorsArray = @[@"red", @"blue", @"white"];
```

You can then use indexOfObject to get the index of a particular string.

```
car_colors carColor = [carColorsArray indexOfObject:@"blue"] + 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of great answers to this here: [Converting between C enum and XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242914/converting-between-c-enum-and-xml)

They are basically the same as Abizern's, but are a little cleaner and easier to work with if your app does this string-to-enum conversion a lot. There are solutions which keep the string and enum definitions together, and ways to make the conversions each a single, easy-to-read line of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
// ...
typedef enum {
    One = 0,
    Two,
    Three
} GFN;
// ...
#define kGFNPrefix @"GFNEnum_"
// ...
+ (NSString *)gfnToStr:(GFN)gfn {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", kGFNPrefix, gfn];
}

+ (GFN)gfnFromStr:(NSString *)str {
    NSString *gfnStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:kGFNPrefix withString:@""];
    return [gfnStr intValue];
}
// ...
```

My choice =)

Answer (score -6):

I found the solution:

```
if ([car_color isEqualToString:@"1"])
        return red;
if ([tipo_pdi isEqualToString:@"2"])
        return blue;
if ([tipo_pdi isEqualToString:@"3"])
        return white;
```

But I don't like this 'if' style, what if I had a thousand colors? Isn't there a more automatic solution?

Comment: A dictionary - As I said in my answer.

Comment: I won't vote you down, but what you are doing is just wrong. The answer by @Tom is much better than doing this.