# Best way to enum NSString

Tags: ios, xcode, enums

Im digging for ways to enum objc object such as NSString, I remember there a new feature in a version of Xcode4+ which offering a new way to enum , but not clearly. Anyone know that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [enum Values to NSString (iOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331762/enum-values-to-nsstring-ios)

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331762/enum-values-to-nsstring-ios - I believe that might be a more elegant solution to this issue.

Comment: It would be better if you specifically said in the question title "in Objective-C". see unrelated answers below...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

OK, I answered myself. Guess I make a mistake.

This is the new feature I mentioned above:

```
typedef enum Language : NSUInteger{
     ObjectiveC,
     Java, 
     Ruby, 
     Python, 
    Erlang 
}Language;
```

It's just a new syntax for enum in Xcode 4.4, but I'm so foolish to think we can exchange "NSUInteger" to "NSString".

So here is the way I found that works:

http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/12/01/not-so-nasty-enums-in-objective-c/

```
// Place this in your .h file, outside the @interface block
typedef enum {
    JPG,
    PNG,
    GIF,
    PVR
} kImageType;
#define kImageTypeArray @"JPEG", @"PNG", @"GIF", @"PowerVR", nil

...

// Place this in the .m file, inside the @implementation block
// A method to convert an enum to string
-(NSString*) imageTypeEnumToString:(kImageType)enumVal
{
    NSArray *imageTypeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:kImageTypeArray];
    return [imageTypeArray objectAtIndex:enumVal];
}

// A method to retrieve the int value from the NSArray of NSStrings
-(kImageType) imageTypeStringToEnum:(NSString*)strVal
{
    NSArray *imageTypeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:kImageTypeArray];
    NSUInteger n = [imageTypeArray indexOfObject:strVal];
    if(n < 1) n = JPG;
    return (kImageType) n;
}
```

FYI. The original author of the second example code created a category for enum handling. Just the thing for adding to your very own NSArray class definition.

```
@interface NSArray (EnumExtensions)

- (NSString*) stringWithEnum: (NSUInteger) enumVal;
- (NSUInteger) enumFromString: (NSString*) strVal default: (NSUInteger) def;
- (NSUInteger) enumFromString: (NSString*) strVal;

@end

@implementation NSArray (EnumExtensions)

- (NSString*) stringWithEnum: (NSUInteger) enumVal
{
    return [self objectAtIndex:enumVal];
}

- (NSUInteger) enumFromString: (NSString*) strVal default: (NSUInteger) def
{
    NSUInteger n = [self indexOfObject:strVal];
    if(n == NSNotFound) n = def;
    return n;
}

- (NSUInteger) enumFromString: (NSString*) strVal
{
    return [self enumFromString:strVal default:0];
}

@end
```

Comment: Link is not found :-(

Answer (score 28):

Alternative way to use struct:

```
extern const struct AMPlayerStateReadable
{
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *ready;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *completed;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *playing;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *paused;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *broken;
} AMPlayerState;

const struct AMPlayerStateReadable AMPlayerState =
{
    .ready = @"READY",
    .completed = @"COMPLETE",
    .playing = @"PLAYING",
    .paused = @"PAUSED",
    .broken = @"BROKEN"
};
```

Then you can use like this:

```
NSString *status = AMPlayerState.ready;
```

Easy to use, readable.
Would be nice if someone update/edit answer with advantages/disadvantages of this approach.

Answer (score 17):

Recommended way from apple docs:

> You use the NS_TYPED_ENUM to group constants with a raw value type that you specify. Use NS_TYPED_ENUM for sets of constants that can't logically have values added in a Swift extension, and use NS_TYPED_EXTENSIBLE_ENUM for sets of constants that can be expanded in an extension.
>   [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/grouping_related_objective-c_constants)

```
typedef NSString *MyEnum NS_TYPED_ENUM;
extern MyEnum const MyEnumFirstValue;
extern MyEnum const MyEnumSecondValue;
extern MyEnum const MyEnumThirdValue;
```

in the .h file. Define your strings in the .m file

```
MyEnum const MyEnumFirstValue = @"MyEnumFirstValue"
MyEnum const MyEnumSecondValue = @"MyEnumSecondValue";
MyEnum const MyEnumThirdValue = @"MyEnumThirdValue";
```

Works as expected in both Objective-C

```
- (void)methodWithMyEnum:(MyEnum)myEnum { }
```

and Swift

```
func method(_ myEnum: MyEnum) { }
```

Comment: Amazing how many bad answers I had to read till this one. I KNEW it existed, and I knew there MUST be a new ObjC compiler directive for this - same way "non-optionals" were introduced for smoother bridging with swift. but I couldn't find the Apple docs for the life of me. Great. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This will be validated by compiler, so you won't mix up indices accidentally.

```
NSDictionary *stateStrings =
 @{
   @(MCSessionStateNotConnected) : @"MCSessionStateNotConnected",
   @(MCSessionStateConnecting) : @"MCSessionStateConnecting",
   @(MCSessionStateConnected) : @"MCSessionStateConnected",
  };
NSString *stateString = [stateStrings objectForKey:@(state)];
```

<nbsp;>

```
var stateStrings: [MCSessionState: String] = [
    MCSessionState.NotConnected : "MCSessionState.NotConnected",
    MCSessionState.Connecting : "MCSessionState.Connecting",
    MCSessionState.Connected : "MCSessionState.Connected"
]
var stateString = stateStrings[MCSessionState.Connected]
```

---

UPDATE: A more Swifty way is to extend the enum with `CustomStringConvertible` conformance. Also, this way the compiler will safeguard to implement every new addition to the underlying enum (whereas using arrays does not), as `switch` statements must be exhaustive.

```
extension MCSessionState: CustomStringConvertible {
    
    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .notConnected:
            return "MCSessionState.notConnected"
        case .connecting:
            return "MCSessionState.connecting"
        case .connected:
            return "MCSessionState.connected"
        @unknown default:
            return "Unknown"
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// You can use it like this.
var stateString = MCSessionState.connected.description

// Or this.
var stateString = "\(MCSessionState.connected)"
```

Answer (score 8):

### Update in 2017

Recent down votes drew my attention, and I'd like to add that `enum` is really easy to work with `String` now:

```
enum HTTPMethod: String {
    case GET, POST, PUT
}

HTTPMethod.GET.rawValue == "GET" // it's true
```

### Original Answer

Unfortunately I ended up using:

```
#define HLCSRestMethodGet       @"GET"
#define HLCSRestMethodPost      @"POST"
#define HLCSRestMethodPut       @"PUT"
#define HLCSRestMethodDelete    @"DELETE"
typedef NSString*               HLCSRestMethod;
```

I know this is not what OP asked, but writing actual code to implement enum seems to be an overkill to me. I would consider enum as a language feature (from C) and if I have to write code, I would come up with some better classes that does more than enum does.

### Update

Swift version seems to be prettier, although the performance can never be as good.

```
struct LRest {
    enum HTTPMethod: String {
        case Get = "GET"
        case Put = "PUT"
        case Post = "POST"
        case Delete = "DELETE"
    }
    struct method {
        static let get = HTTPMethod.Get
        static let put = HTTPMethod.Put
        static let post = HTTPMethod.Post
        static let delete = HTTPMethod.Delete
    }
```

}

Comment: I would also rather go with this approach than lines on lines of code for something this simple. You don't lose too much from not using enum too.

Comment: The question was about introducing such enumerated NSStrings in Objective-C. Not Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the inline array function. eg

```
@[@"stringone",@"stringtwo",@"stringthree"];
```

if not, i'm not sure you can enum objects.

you could however have a static array of strings and have the enum reference object at index.

Comment: Yeah, I make a mistake about it. (see my own answer below).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, although it's not perfect. I feel the switch mechanism could be improved... also not positive about hash-collision resistance, don't know what apple uses under the hood.

```
#define ElementProperty NSString *
#define __ElementPropertiesList @[@"backgroundColor", @"scale", @"alpha"]

#define epBackgroundColor __ElementPropertiesList[0]
#define epScale __ElementPropertiesList[1]
#define epAlpha __ElementPropertiesList[2]

#define switchElementProperty(__ep) switch(__ep.hash)
#define caseElementProperty(__ep) case(__ep.hash)
```

```
-(void)setValue:(id)value forElementProperty:(ElementProperty)ep;
```

```
[self setValue:@(1.5) forElementProperty:epScale];
```

```
//Compiler unfortunately won't warn you if you are missing a case
switchElementProperty(myProperty) {
    caseElementProperty(epBackgroundColor):
        NSLog(@"bg");
        break;
    caseElementProperty(epScale):
        NSLog(@"s");
        break;
    caseElementProperty(epAlpha):
        NSLog(@"a");
        break;
}
```