# How to convert a Swift enum: String into an Objective-C enum: NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, nsstring

I am having an issue converting this swift enum to Objective-C :

```
 public enum ISO8601Format: String {

case Year = "yyyy" // 1997
case YearMonth = "yyyy-MM" // 1997-07
case Date = "yyyy-MM-dd" // 1997-07-16
case DateTime = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ" // 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00
case DateTimeSec = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" // 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00
case DateTimeMilliSec = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" // 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00

    init(dateString:String) {
        switch dateString.characters.count {
        case 4:
            self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.Year.rawValue)!
        case 7:
            self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.YearMonth.rawValue)!
        case 10:
            self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.Date.rawValue)!
        case 22:
            self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.DateTime.rawValue)!
        case 25:
            self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.DateTimeSec.rawValue)!
        default:// 28:
            self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.DateTimeMilliSec.rawValue)!
        }
    }
}

public enum DateFormat {
case ISO8601(ISO8601Format?), DotNet, RSS, AltRSS, Custom(String)
}
```

I already researched this everywhere and found this and this:

[Best way to enum NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171907/best-way-to-enum-nsstring)

[enum Values to NSString (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331762/enum-values-to-nsstring-ios)

Didn't quite understand those answers.I am looking for more elegant solutions (if there are any) or better explanations of those answers with modern objective-c syntax.

Thank you !

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of the enum. It's a very strange usage of an enum.

Comment: Doesn't seem *that* strange a use of enums to me (seeing as Apple has shown [representing a barcode with an enum](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID148)!). There isn't going to be any "elegant solution" for converting it to Objective-C. In C, enums are just glorified integers - unlike in Swift where they're *way* more powerful. You'll have to wrap the enum in extra logic to convert an integer value of your enum to a string, as the answers to the questions you linked to show.

Comment: Although I'm very confused why you're doing `self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.Year.rawValue)!`.... why not just `self = .Year`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString * const ISO8601DateFormatType = @"ISO8601";
NSString * const DotNetDateFormatType = @"DotNet";
NSString * const RSSDateFormatType = @"RSS";
NSString * const AltRSSDateFormatType = @"AltRSS";
NSString * const CustomDateFormatType = @"Custom";

NSString * const ISOFormatYear = @"yyyy";
NSString * const ISOFormatYearMonth = @"yyyy-MM"; // 1997-07
NSString * const ISOFormatDate = @"yyyy-MM-dd"; // 1997-07-16
NSString * const ISOFormatDateTime = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ"; // 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00
NSString * const ISOFormatDateTimeSec = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"; // 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00
NSString * const ISOFormatDateTimeMilliSec = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"; // 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00

@interface DateFormat : NSObject 

    + (instancetype) ISODateFormat: (NSString *) isoFormat;
    + (instancetype) DotNetDateFormat;
    + (instancetype) RSSDateFormat;
    + (instancetype) AltRSSDateFormat;
    + (instancetype) CustomDateFormat: (NSString *) formatString;

    @property (readonly) NSString *dateFormatType;
    @property (readonly) NSString *formatDetails;

@end

@implementation DateFormat

- (instancetype) initWithType: (NSString *) formatType details: (NSString *) details {

    if(self = [super init]) {
        _dateFormatType = formatType;
        _formatDetails = details;
    }

    return self;
}

+ (instancetype) ISODateFormat: (NSString *) isoFormat
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: ISO8601DateFormatType details: isoFormat];
}

+ (instancetype) DotNetDateFormat
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: DotNetDateFormatType details: nil];
}

+ (instancetype) RSSDateFormat
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: RSSDateFormatType details: nil];
}

+ (instancetype) AltRSSDateFormat
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: AltRSSDateFormatType details: nil];
}

+ (instancetype) CustomDateFormat: (NSString *) formatString
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: CustomDateFormatType details: formatString];
}

@end
```